# Nothing happens if i click the button

Tags: java, android

My Code

```
public class start extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle ici) {
    super.onCreate(ici);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);


    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(start.this, QuestionActivity.class);
            start.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
```

> Not sure if it finds the button but ther is no error

```
    final Button button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(start.this, QuestionActivity.class);
            start.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });


}
```

Nothing happens if I click the Button.
If I just write

```
           Intent myIntent = new Intent(start.this, QuestionActivity.class);
           start.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

It works.

I am new to programming so please be kind :)
Please help

Comment: check the button id is same as you mention in `findViewById()` ....

Comment: what is button5 and button1 ? 2 buttons or its single button ?

Comment: 2 different buttons

Comment: check answer below its your simple mistake instead of button5 you used button ......

Comment: `button.setOnClickListener` must be `button5.setOnClickListener`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the button name ....

```
 final Button button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
//  use button5 instead of button below one
button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {   
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(start.this, QuestionActivity.class);
            start.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

you first define `button` and set the listener but then you define `button5` and set the listener to `button` again. so `button5` wont do anything. the true code is like below:

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(start.this, QuestionActivity.class);
        start.this.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
});

final Button button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(start.this, QuestionActivity.class);
        start.this.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
});
```

Comment: vote up and accept as the answer if it was helpgul ;)